# Using GetWindowDC for drawing

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I'm having difficulties in using Win API GetWindowDC to get a valid hDC for drawing.

I'm using vb.net 2013, and I tried to bitblt images to a form, draw string, draw rectangle, and nothing.

I'm running in Win7 all the tests.

Do I have to disable aero with DWM functions, is it a handle trick, or what is? I already posted a "draw in titlebar vb.net 2013" question that had no answer, where I have some code used, but right now, I just need a working example to start. All help is appreciated.

---

But here goes some more code that doesn't work either.

```
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case WinAPI.Win32Messages.WM_NCPAINT

            Dim hDC As IntPtr = WinAPI.GetWindowDC(m.HWnd)
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(hDC)

            g.DrawString("TESTE", New Font("ARIAL", 16), New SolidBrush(Color.Black), 5, 5)
            g.Dispose()

            WinAPI.ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hDC)
```

The error is OutOfMemory, and nothing gets drawn anywhere, even with tests done to clientarea.

It's a simple purpose. Getting to draw in all the areas of a form, and from that on, I'll handle the drawing.

Well, thanks at least for the help on correctly editing. About the Graphics.FromHDC, yes, I tried it.

But here goes some more code that doesn't work either.

```
Select Case m.Msg
    Case WinAPI.Win32Messages.WM_NCPAINT

        Dim hDC As IntPtr = WinAPI.GetWindowDC(m.HWnd)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(hDC)

        g.DrawString("TESTE", New Font("ARIAL", 16), New SolidBrush(Color.Black), 5, 5)
        g.Dispose()

        WinAPI.ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hDC)
```

The error is OutOfMemory, and nothing gets drawn anywhere, even with tests done to clientarea.

It's a simple purpose. Getting to draw in all the areas of a form, and from that on, I'll handle the drawing. And too bad for the negative votes. Doesn't help, cause if people where fast on the negative voting...try to be as fast on reading all of what's placed in a question, and finding out that it is not just "gimme gimme codez" - the other referenced question has code.

People that know a lot forget that once you where like me, and didn't know a lot about the subject...might not even know how to ask the right questions...

Thanks for the help, if someone can provide it.

Comment: *"Plz giev me teh codez"* is not something that should be part of a question on stackoverflow. You need to show **your** code, and ask a specific question. Do you want to render to the client area or the non-client area of a window? Is the application under your control? What have you tried? How did that fail?

Comment: The documentation for [WM_NCPAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212.aspx) contains working sample code.

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics.FromHwnd()` takes a window handle, not a DC (the clue is in the name). Try `Graphics.FromHdc()` instead.

Comment: Yes. I tried that as the first run, but nothing happened. No errors, but nothing was drawn.